# http to https and www to non-www not working correct with laravel 8 URI links

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-8

I searched a lot of about this topic to redirect all urls to https://my-domain

I want delete the www and add https.

I found a lot of answers this one work good

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

but the problem its just working with the home page link. for example:
when I write

https://www.example.com it redirect to => https://example.com

but the problem is when i try: https://www.example.com/about-us

its redirect ti https://example.com/index.php how can i solve that I am using Laravel 8

I want all type of URL to non-www and https. and how can I redirect index.php and index.html to https://example.com/

This is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
  </IfModule>

  RewriteEngine On

  # Handle Authorization Header
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
  RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

  # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
  RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

  # Handle Front Controller...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
  
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You are doing these things in the wrong order. The block after `# Handle Front Controller...` makes it rewrite all requests for non-existing files or folders to the index.php. Your external redirect should come before that, not after.

Comment: @CBroe Cool Bro now its not redirect to index.php but for example if any one access like that ```https://example.com/index.php``` how can I remove the index.php and index.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.